# Ruby on Rails - Activerecord, select specific data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is my shema :

```
class Media< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :videos
end
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :media
end
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :media
end
```

Is it possible to get all medias that correspond to the model picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) - it will return you all `medias` which have at least single `picture` associated:

```
Media.joins(:pictures)
```

If you mean to get the specific `picture`'s media, then you just use the method provided by association:

```
Picture.first.media
```

Comment: will it work, or will it raise an error/warning or sth like that?

Comment: @marmeladze I am not sure. The only possible issue here, is that Rails' [`Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) might get lost. But that's easy fixed :)